# How do you import an xkcd fig to html using mpld3

Tags: html, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython, mpld3

I am trying to import a matplotlib to html with xkcd theme.  My code is as follows (no data,just a fig)

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor = '#eee8d5')
#plt.matplotlib.rcdefaults()
with plt.xkcd():

     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

     ax.set_axis_bgcolor('#eee8d5') #set_color('#fdf6e3')

     ax.title.set_color('#d33682') # Magenta

     ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#657b83')
     ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#657b83')


     ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#657b83')
     ax.spines['left'].set_color('#657b83')
     ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
     ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

     ax.set_title('Title', fontsize = 18);
     html = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
     Html_file= open("CumPrctWordFrq.html","w")
     Html_file.write(html)
     Html_file.close()
```

So far so good -- everything renders correctly in the python notebook.  However when I paste the html on a website (squarespace), the fig loses all the xkcd properties.  Eventually I would like to make this interactive.  The idea is eventually to produce a xkcd -> solarized -> interactive plot.

Comment: Actually this only works in the notebook because the inline backend is used to draw the figure and not mpld3. I fear the _xkcd_ style is not implemented in mpld3 yet.

Comment: Thanks @Jakob - I suppose when [MEP25](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/wiki/MEP25) is resolved then passing plots from one plotting package to another (for additional functionality) will be trivial.  More of a question than a statement.

Comment: It did you find an alternative solution to `mpld3` to display the xckd style graphs?

Comment: No.  In the end I just ended up a .png of the image from matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mpld3` does not yet support the `plt.xkcd()` mode.  If this is something you want, you should creat an issue in [the `mpld3` issue tracker](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues), and see if someone is inspired to work on it.

Comment: Yes.  I did not want to add something so trivial to the wish list